# Need help identifying a mystery diode!

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image]I really need some help identifying this diode.  I contacted ON Semiconductor's technical support and they couldn't tell me what it is, even though it is a Fairchild Semiconductor diode (ON owns Fairchild now I guess).

I am attaching a picture of this diode.  It has a Fairchild logo "F" followed by three lines of code "523" "IC" and "F8."

If you can help me out with this, or point me in the direction of someone who can, I would be very thankful.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Better on the electrical stack...

Comment: Might this old Fairchild catalogue be useful? http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/components/fairchild/_dataBooks/1975_Fairchild_Full_Line_Condensed_Catalog.pdf